# C Memory leaks to free for a Linked List

Tags: c, memory-leaks, linked-list, valgrind, free

When I valgrind, I have **memory leaks and errors (errors are in another test file)** in my **main.c**. (screen at the end)
Also, I have to free **only** in my function **list_destroy** in list.c !
Check this out :

EDIT : thanks to @kirjosieppo I removed a malloc in create_cell function below ! Now : [valgrind_updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4oSD.png)

**cell.c**

```
// cell_s has gpointer ptr_value and struct cell_s *next
cell_t* create_cell(gpointer v) {
    cell_t *c = malloc(sizeof(cell_t));
    c->next = NULL;
    c->ptr_value = v;

    return c;
}

void destroy_int(gpointer data) {
    free((int *) data);
}
```

**list.c**

```
// list_s has cell_t *head and int size
list_t* list_create() {
    list_t *l = malloc(sizeof(list_t));

    l->head = NULL;
    l->size = 0;

    return l;
}

void list_insert_in_head(list_t *l, gpointer element) {
// typedef cell_t* adr
    adr address_c = create_cell(element);

    address_c->next = l->head;
    l->head = address_c;

    ++l->size;
}

void list_insert_next(list_t *l, gpointer element, adr address) {
    adr address_c = create_cell(element);

    if (l->head == NULL) {
        liste_insert_in_head(l, element);
    } else {
        address_c->next = address->next;
        address->next = address_c;
    }

    ++l->size;
} 

void list_remove_in_head(list_t *l) {
    if (l->head != NULL) {
        l->head = l->head->next;
    }

    --l->size;
}

void list_remove_after(list_t *l, adr address) {
    if (l->head->next == NULL) {
        printf("Use list_remove_in_head function\n");
    } else if (address != NULL) {
        address->next = address->next->next;

        --l->size;
    }
}

// Here is the problem !
void list_destroy(list_t *l, list_gfree ft_destroy) {
    adr current = l->head;

    while(current != NULL) {
        adr tmp = current;

        current = current->next;
        
        ft_destroy(tmp->ptr_value);
        tmp->ptr_value = NULL;
        
        ft_destroy(tmp);
    }

    free(l);
}
```

**main.c**

```
int main(void) {
    list_t *l = list_create();

    int *ptr_int = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *ptr_int = 4;
    list_insert_in_head(l, ptr_int);
    printf("Size : %d\n", l->size);

    int *ptr_int_2 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *ptr_int_2 = 7;
    list_insert_in_head(l, ptr_int_2);
    printf("Size : %d\n", l->size);

    int *ptr_int_3 = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *ptr_int_3 = 100;
    list_insert_next(l, ptr_int_3, l->head);
    printf("Size : %d\n", l->size);

    list_remove_in_head(l);
    printf("Size : %d\n", l->size);

    list_remove_next(l, l->head);
    printf("Size : %d\n", l->size);

    list_remove_next(l, l->size);
    printf("Size : %d\n", l->size);

    list_destroy(l, destroy_int);
}
```

**valgrind**
Memory leaks are detected in my **insertions**.
[valgrind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k36Gr.png)

Thanks for helping me to have 0 memory leaks and 0 errors ! :-)

Comment: As a problem solving strategy, the first thing you can do when encountering this is to isolate the issue.  Check if leaks occur if you only create and destroy the list.  Then add one node and test.  Test insertion at the head, middle and tail.  Test deletion at the head, middle, and tail.  If you've done this, and then come up with the program as written as a minimum reproducible example, then you should explain that this is what you did.  But I don't think you are there yet, because the process of isolating the problem will identify exactly which function creates the problem.

Comment: @paddy I already did that and the leaks occurs when I insert a node (at the head and after a specific node). I don't know why. :/
When I create a list without node, it's ok. And I said that at the end : "Memory leaks are detected in my insertions."

Comment: You call `list_insert_in_head` twice (for `ptr_int` and `ptr_int_2`). Is this on purpose?

Comment: @kirjosieppo I inserted at the head 4 (ptr_int) and also inserted at the head 7 (ptr_int_2). So, yeah, I called list_insert_in_head twice for this test file :)

Comment: Ah sorry, now I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven’t yet tested if that really is the (only) issue, but there’s a code like this:

```c
create_cell(gpointer v) {
// clip
    c->ptr_value = malloc(sizeof(int));
    c->ptr_value = v;
```

An allocation is made and then the pointer is thrown away.

Let’s continue! What else is there to be found?

In `list_remove_in_head()` the cell `l->head` is written over and not freed. It can be fixed with something like this:

```c
void list_remove_in_head(list_t *l) {
    if (l->head != NULL) {
        void *tmp = l->head->next;
        free(l->head->ptr_value);
        free(l->head);
        l->head = tmp;
    }

    --l->size;
}
```

The same applies to `list_remove_after()`, too, but I suppose you can work it out yourself. :)

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem about these 2 lines of create_cell function. I don't think there is a problem about this function. I think that the problem is in the list_destroy function
What is // clip comment ?

Comment: Well, *clip* means simply "some lines left out". However, here we have an invocation of `malloc` whose pointer is immediately discarded by writing over. (pardon my English, I’m quite tired)

Comment: I got it for clip. Ah the multiple malloc of my main.c file is the problem, it's not necessary right ? :-)

Comment: Yeah, the allocation that actually goes to the list is that which is made in `main`. The additional malloc in `create_cell` is surplus.

Comment: Ok I removed create_cell malloc and now I get less leaks, nice ! Thanks !
Less allocations :) (11 to 8 allocs)
Same free (4 to 4 frees)

Comment: Hey ! Just about the frees, the frees must be done in list_destroy only but I dont know how to do it. Otherwise it would have been too easy. :)
Should I change the return of my remove function to get the cell to free in my list_destroy function ?

Comment: How about giving a `ft_destroy` function to the remove functions?

Comment: I can but I would have preferred to do without any free in my functions remove

Comment: Cells are implemented as dynamically allocates structs. Surely the memory should be freed when a cell in removed. The other option is of course to return the cell but then it must dealt with in the main()

Comment: @kirjoseppo Ok I see ! Thanks for helping me. I green check your answer. :)